# ncurses getch() weird output?

Tags: c++, char, ncurses

I have installed the ncurses.h lib and started experimenting with the getch() function.When I built and run this code which seems alright to me at first, the console printed out a weird character: '�'(if it doesn't show and shows as a space here is a screen shot: https://prnt.sc/gbrp7b) The console starts spamming it but if I type a character, it shows up in the output but still the '�' spams. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char input;

    while(true){

        input = getch();

        cout << "You entered : " << input << endl;


        //break;
    }


 return 0;
}
```

So I thought of trying to use an if statement to try and stop it spamming but the code doesn't recognise the character:

It gives this error:

```
error: character too large for enclosing character literal type
```

For this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char input;

    while(true){

        input = getch();
        if(input!='�'){
            cout << "YOu entered : " << input << endl;
        }


    }


 return 0;
}
```

I am on OSX Sierra 10.12.5 and using eclipse Oxygen

Comment: To begin with [`getch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/curs_getch.3x.html) have a return type of *`int`*. And that mysterious character is probably something your terminal can't show, not the actual `'�'` character you attempt to compare with.

Comment: Furthermore I suggest you read e.g. [this tutorial on ncurses](http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html), especially the section about [*initializing it*](http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html#init).

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `ncurses` with `initscr()` and close it with `endwin()` functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char input;

    initscr();

    while (true) {
        input = getch();
        cout << "YOu entered : " << input << endl;
    }

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```